# How to remove &nbsp; with javascript this case?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a question.

```
<table id="mytable">
 <tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>4</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>7</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td>8</td>
  <td>9</td>
  <td>10</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

and here is script.

```
var table = document.getElementById("mytable");
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  for (var k = 0; k < 5; k++) {
    var str = table.rows[i].cells[k].innerHTML;
    alert(str);
  }
};
```

I try to code this

```
alert(str.replace(/(&nbsp;)*/g,''))
```

but then empty alert box show up.

I want to pop up cells value expect &nb sp; and empty box.

---

[image: show up '&nbsp']
show up '&nbsp'. I don't want it.

[image: show up '']
show up "". I don't want it.

[image: I want this!]
I want this. Thank you for comment.

```
        var str = table.rows[i].cells[k].innerHTML.replace(/[&]nbsp[;]/gi,"");
         if (str.length > 0) {
          alert(str);
        }
```

Comment: If you `expect &nb sp;` then you need to replace the `&nbsp` with `&nb sp`, not with an empty string..?

Comment: Isn't an empty alert what you want?

Comment: Just [trim](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) `str` and then [check the length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else) of it, if greater than `0`, alert the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the `innerHtml` of `td` with empty string by Regex and check the length of string. If the length is bigger than 0, alert that.

```js
var table = document.getElementById("mytable");
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  for (var k = 0; k < 5; k++) {
    var str = table.rows[i].cells[k].innerHTML;
    str = str.replace(/(&nbsp;)*/g, '');
    if (str.length) alert(str);
  }
};
```

```html
<table id="mytable">
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>7</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```