# why is there a <td>&nbsp;</td> in my gridview ASP.NET

Tags: html, css, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview which is generated by asp.net. I have a id row which I have hidden using css. However this causes a visual problem here is the problem in question.

[image: gridview with wrong td]

I know that the problem is caused due to the last td in the html that looks like this  `<td>&nbsp;</td>.`

Has you can see on this image.
[image: problematique code]

when i remove that line of code it works and my gridview looks like this.
[image: grid i want to have]

why does asp generate this code `<td>&nbsp;</td>`. how can i remove it any help would be very appreciated thank you.

Here is the code for my gridview

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvLocation" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" ShowFooter="true" 
            ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true" AllowPaging="True" OnPageIndexChanging="gvLocation_PageIndexChanging"
            OnRowEditing="gvLocation_RowEditing" OnRowCancelingEdit="gvLocation_RowCancelingEdit"
            AllowSorting="true" onsorting="gvLocation_Sorting" ridLines="None" CssClass="mGrid" PagerStyle-CssClass="pgr" AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alt" CellPadding="3">
            <%-- Theme Properties --%>
            <Columns>  
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Armario" SortExpression="armario">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label CssClass="gridTextbox" ID="lblCloset" Text='<%# Eval("armario")%>' runat="server" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox CssClass="gridTextbox" ID="txtCloset" Text='<%# Eval("armario")%>' runat="server" />
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox CssClass="gridTextbox" ID="txtClosetFooter" runat="server" />
                    </FooterTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>  
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Cajon" SortExpression="cajon">
                    <ItemTemplate>                       
                        <asp:Label CssClass="gridTextbox" ID="lblDrawer" Text='<%# Eval("cajon")%>' runat="server" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox CssClass="gridTextbox" ID="txtDrawer" Text='<%# Eval("cajon")%>' runat="server" />
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox  CssClass="gridTextbox" ID="txtDrawerFooter" runat="server" />
                    </FooterTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>       
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:ImageButton ImageUrl="~/Images/edit.png" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" ToolTip="Edit" Width="20px" Height="20px"/>
                        <asp:ImageButton ImageUrl="~/Images/delete.png" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" ToolTip="Delete" Width="20px" Height="20px"  OnClick="deleteItem"/>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:ImageButton ImageUrl="~/Images/save.png" runat="server" CommandName="Update" ToolTip="Update" Width="20px" Height="20px"  OnClick="updateItem"/>
                        <asp:ImageButton ImageUrl="~/Images/cancel.png" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" ToolTip="Cancel" Width="20px" Height="20px"/>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        <asp:ImageButton ImageUrl="~/Images/addnew.png" ID="addNewLocation" runat="server" CommandName="AddNew" ToolTip="Add New" Width="20px" Height="20px" OnClick="addNew"/>
                    </FooterTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ubicacion id" SortExpression="ubicacion_componente_id" ItemStyle-CssClass="hideGridColumn" HeaderStyle-CssClass="hideGridColumn">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label CssClass="gridTextbox" ID="lblLocationID"  Text='<%# Eval("ubicacion_componente_id")%>' runat="server" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>  
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

Add here is the code for the css that hides the first id column

```
.hideGridColumn
{
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide your HTML for the gridview & the css that affects it.

Comment: I gave you the my asp add css codes is that what you needed.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 solution for you to remove redundant `<td>&nbsp;</td>`

Javascript version

```
var table = document.getElementById("mytable");
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  for (var k = 0; k < 5; k++) {
    var str = table.rows[i].cells[k].innerHTML;
    str = str.replace(/(&nbsp;)*/g, '');
    if (str.length) alert(str);
  }
};
```

[How to remove &nbsp; with javascript this case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50384117/how-to-remove-nbsp-with-javascript-this-case)

Jquery version

```
$(function() {
  $("table tr").each(function() {
    var tds = $(this).find("td"); //find all td
    var descriptionTD = tds.eq(1); //get the td for the description

    //get the remaining tds that only contain "&nbsp;"
    var emptytds = tds.not(descriptionTD).filter(function() {
      return $(this).html() === "&nbsp;";
    });

    //if all the remaing tds are empty
    if (emptytds.length === tds.length - 1) {
      emptytds.remove();
      descriptionTD.prop("colspan", tds.length).prop("width", "100%");
    }
  });
});
```

[remove <td> that has &nbsp; and make sub header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30674559/remove-td-that-has-nbsp-and-make-sub-header)

Comment: I have tried to add the javascript in my aspx file but it doesn't seems to work. Here is the code I added what am I doing wrong?  <script>
    var table = document.getElementById("PageContent_gvLocation");
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (var k = 0; k < 5; k++) {
            var str = table.rows[i].cells[k].innerHTML;
            str = str.replace(/(&nbsp;)*/g, '');
            if (str.length) alert(str);
        }
    };
</script>
When I run the javascript I get this error TypeError: Cannot read property 'rows' of null

Comment: you should move it to window.onload event

Comment: I have got the the javascript to run a popup appears a couple of times but the last <td>&nbsp;</td> is not removed.

Answer (score 0):

```
<td>&nbsp;</td>
```

Its the recommended pattern, cause it works on every browser. Try to run your table without &nbsp in Edge Browser, you will see that breaks the table layout.

```
 <td>/td>
```

[Without '&nbsp'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ssyXb.png)

```
<td>&nbsp;</td>
```

[With '&nbsp'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQzjw.png)

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be many, I managed to solve it by including a tag in the GridView.

`ShowFooter = "false"`

it solved it for me, I had the same problem.